# Fix pkcon error cannot found file

Tags: fedora, packagekit

My disk is full and I found that PackageKit uses more than 12GB in cache folder.
So I found that I can delete the cached files.
I used the following command

`[unix@localhost ~]$ sudo pkcon -c 8000000 refresh`
`Refreshing cache              [=========================]`
`Loading cache                 [=========================]`  
  `Downloading repository information[=========================]` 
`Finished                      [=========================]` 
`Fatal error: Error when getting information for file “/var/cache/PackageKit/28/metadata`
 ``` /phracek-PyCharm/repodata``/36899dd8cb609ee8604863268813e848e6d48b2448bad93a4037e14dcad30dcd-appstream.xml”: No such ``` 
 `file or directory`

But I have this error about missing files and folders.
Could some one help me to fix it?

Comment: May I ask which version of Fedora you are using?

Comment: @telometto an old one :) 28

Comment: Just out of curiosity: why are you running such an old version? Is it some hardware compatibility issues?

Comment: @telometto I have installed a lot of softwares like Matlab and I dont trust to make a new setup.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you absolutely need it, you can disable and mask PackageKit. I did some digging on Bugzilla and it seems to be an issue with < 28 of Fedora and PackageKit version < 1.1.19.

The "solution" (except upgrading the distro and/or package version), seems to be to be to disable & mask PackageKit:

```
sudo systemctl stop packagekit.service
sudo systemctl disable packagekit.service
sudo systemctl mask packagekit.service
sudo systemctl stop packagekit-offline-update.service
sudo systemctl disable packagekit-offline-update.service
sudo systemctl mask packgekit-offline-update.service

sudo rm -rf /var/cache/PackageKit   # optional
```

I don't know which version of `systemd` Fedora 28 uses, but if it is >= 220, you can pass the `disable --now` flag instead of stopping each service.

**PS:** If you want to use GNOME Software, you'll have to `unmask` and start the services again. But I don't think this should be a problem if you're comfortable updating your system using the CLI.